# Timer with input, sound and flashing ( Just timer :) )

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, timer, pyqt

I know that this program is not very outstanding, but I'm learning "Python" and decided to publish this code in order to get some advice and parting words and overall evaluation of the program. This is a simple timer with the ability to enter the desired number of minutes, start and reset functions.

As a beginner, it is very important for me to get any feedback from professionals who will accurately point out mistakes and shortcomings. I used PyQt5 (it's a python library)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QSound
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import time
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)


        self.setWindowTitle("Таймер")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1))
        self.setMinimumSize(1200, 500)
    

        #кнопка старта
        self.btn_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_start.setText("Старт")
        self.btn_start.move(50, 50)
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)

        #кнопка сброса
        self.btn_reset = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_reset.setText("Сброс")
        self.btn_reset.move(50, 300)
        self.btn_reset.clicked.connect(self.reset)

        #место ввода
        self.input_text = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.input_text.setText("15")
        self.input_text.setFont(QFont("Arial", 18))
        self.input_text.move(40, 100)
        self.input_text.setMaximumSize(100, 40)
        self.input_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_text.toPlainText()

        #место вывода времени
        self.timer1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.timer1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.timer1.move(100, 40)
    

        #галочка звука
        self.audio = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
        self.audio.setText("Включить звук")
        self.audio.move(40, 175)

        self.blink = False

        #таймер, благодаря которому все работает
        self.timer = QTimer(self)                            
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)                   
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.time = 0

    #функция масштабируемости
    def  resizeEvent(self, e) -> None:
        w = e.size().width()
        h = e.size().height()
    
        #размер окна вывода времени
        c = int(GetSystemMetrics(1) - 50)
        self.timer1.resize(w-350, h-200)
    
        #положение окна вывода времени
        self.timer1.move(int(w/10), int(h/11))
    
        #размер шрифта цифр
        p = int(w / 5)
        self.timer1.setFont(QFont("Arial", p))
    
        QtWidgets.QWidget.resizeEvent(self, e)


    #функция кнопки старта
    def start_timer(self):
         text1 = str(self.input_text.toPlainText())

        #перехват ошибки, дабы неправильный ввод(буквы, запятая, пробелы) обнулялся
        try:
            text2 = float(text1)
        except ValueError:
            text2 = 0
            self.input_text.setText("0")
            self.btn_start.setText("Старт")
            self.input_text.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        
         text3 = float(text2)
         text = text3 * 60

        if self.btn_start.text() == "Старт":
             if not self.time: self.time = text
             self.timer.start()
             self.btn_start.setText("Стоп")
        else:
             self.timer.stop()
             self.btn_start.setText("Старт")


    #ГЛАВНАЯ ФУНКЦИЯ, благодаря ей таймер и работает
      def showTime(self):

            if self.time > 0:
                self.time -= 1
                text1 = self.time

                #превращение в MM:SS
                ty_res = time.gmtime(text1)
                res = time.strftime("%M:%S",ty_res)
                self.timer1.setText(res)

                #делает цифры красными
                if self.time < 61:
                     self.timer1.setStyleSheet("color: #FF0000")
            
                #заставляет цифры мигать
                if self.time < 30:
                    if self.blink == False:
                        self.timer1.hide()
                        self.blink = True
                    else:
                        self.timer1.show()
                        self.blink = False


                if self.time == 0:
                    self.timer1.setText("00:00")
                    self.btn_start.setText("Старт")
                    if self.audio.checkState():
                        QSound.play('C:\\Users\\Users\\user_name\\....\\....\\....wav') #писк при нуле


     #функция кнопки сброса
     def reset(self):
        self.timer.stop()       
        self.btn_start.setText("Старт")
        self.time = 00.00
        self.timer1.setText(str(self.time))
        self.timer1.setStyleSheet("color: #000000")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('C:\\Users\\user_name\\....\\....\\....ico'))

    window = Window()
    window.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('C:\\Users\\user_name\\....\\....\\....ico'))

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Don't use widget.move(), and don't hard code sizes, in hardcoding the layout, your program will only look the way you designed at the specific resolution you targeted, and if you resize the window the layout will definitely break and it won't be what you wanted. Instead use layout classes and let the program handle it for you, in this way you don't need to calculate the sizes and the window will always look the way you intended it to look like.

Comment: And PyQt5 is severely outdated, it will eventually be shifted out, the latest is PyQt6, PyQt5 has wide spread use but most projects that still use PyQt5 came from way back, they hang on using it because of backward compatibility, PyQt5 is much less robust in features than PyQt6. New projects should use PyQt6.